# how to set window location in jquery for rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following url

```
window.location.href = "/test/cat=6?sub_cat=20?mode=red+2010";
```

Untill `/test/cat=6` is clear but

If i print

```
params[:id] it display cat-6 thats fine because it is friendly id
```

If i print

```
params[:sub_cat] it displday 20?mode=red 2010 instead of 20 alone
```

if i print

```
params[:mode] it show nothing
```

How do i get the multiple params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
window.location.href = "/test/cat=6?sub_cat=20&mode=red+2010";
```

The query string starts with an ? other parameters are added with &